# Bidirectional DataBinding in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am writing a page which uses declarative data binding to bind Control values in a web form (inside a repeater) to values from a source DataTable. The binding works great, the repeater's templated controls are filled from the datatable. My understanding however is that using the <# Bind("SourceColumnName") #> sytnax (as opposed to the Eval() syntax) I should be able to get controls which have had their values updated by the user to bind those values *back to the source DataTable*. **Is there a set of circumstances under which a <# Bind("SourceColumnName") #>-type statement will update its source data, not visa versa?** To clarify: I am passing a DataTable object to the DataSource field of the repeater in the codebehind, I am NOT making use of a DataSource Control (which would be attached via the DataSourceID property). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"In general, the Bind method should only be used in an EditItemTemplate and an InsertItemTemplate. It should not be used (or, in fact, required) in an ItemTemplate, AlternatingItemTemplate, or SelectedItemTemplate" (c) [www.15seconds.com/issue/040630.htm](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040630.htm)

That means your container have to have edit capabilities in order to enforce its template to update underlying datasource. Afaik DataRepeater is unable to do that, try to go for either GridView, DetailView or FormView instead.

Answer (score 0):

The repeater doesn't have `Bidirectional databinding` support. You can only create the item using the DataItem.

You have to loop the repeater items and extract the values from the control to update.